# Python ImportError .util module not found

Tags: python, import, module, scikit-learn

I have the following problem using the kmodes package which was recently uploaded:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kmodes/

Running the usage example:

```
import numpy as np

from kmodes import kmodes

data = np.random.choice(20, (100, 10))

km = kmodes.KModes(n_clusters=4, init='Huang', n_init=5, verbose=1)

print(km.cluster_centroids_)

clusters = km.fit_predict(data)
```

I do get an error which looks like this:

```
runfile('/Users/Amine/Documents/Python/Versuch1Kmodes07:06:2016.py', wdir='/Users/Amine/Documents/Python')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/Users/Amine/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/Amine/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 88, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/Amine/Documents/Python/Versuch1Kmodes07:06:2016.py", line 9, in <module>
    from kmodes import kmodes

  File "/Users/Amine/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kmodes/kmodes.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .util import get_max_value_key, encode_features
ImportError: No module named 'kmodes.util'
```

I don’t know the actual problem since I do not understand every line of the error. But what is the `.util` package? I tried to download/install it, but it does not exist in the internet. Is this one causing the problem?

Comment: It is not some package from somewhere, it is internal package from here: https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes/tree/master/kmodes/util Looks like kmodes package has broken imports issue.

Comment: Which means, that this package is still not working correctly? What should I do in order to run the example? I already contacted the guy who wrote this package and I wait for an answer :S

Comment: Yes, I think, this package doesn't work properly. I believe that you can also file issue here: https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes/issues

Comment: thank you very much paul! I contacted him and he fixed this package, now its working properly!